# Auto authenticate HTTP authentication in web-based test

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, http-authentication, arquillian-drone

I am working with Arquillian Drone and Graphene to write web-based tests for our webapplication. The webapplication uses HTTP authentication. When I start the test (I currently use FirefoxDriver, but I guess it would be the same with every other driver), this login-popup appears to enter the credentials:

[image: login]

Then the test pauses and waits till I type in the credentials manually. How do I make the test automatically use declared credentials and login onto the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already have a solution. I pass the credentials directly in the URL.

```
http://<username>:<password>@url.com
```